# Symfony2 - Twig Extension error cannot access empty property

Tags: php, symfony, twig

New to using Twig extensions, can use some help on this—can't figure out what is wrong.

Everything seems to be loading up correctly except with the function call in my extension class.

Am getting the following error:

`FatalErrorException:Error:Cannot access property in /../PostExtension.php line 32`

Line 32:

`public function getPostCount($year, $month)`

**Have been searching for solutions and reading docs for hours and haven't been able to find the solution.** **Any help on this?**

**PostExtension.php**

```
class PostExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
    );
}

public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        'getPostCount' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'getPostCount')
    );
}

public function getPostCount($year, $month)
{
    $post = $this->$em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Post')
        ->getPostCountsByMonth($year, $month);

    return $post;
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'post_extension';
}
}
```

**Twig**

```
{{ getPostCount('2014', 'July') }}
```

**services.yml**

```
services:
    acme.twig.extension:
        class: Acmer\DemoBundle\Twig\PostExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
        arguments:
            em: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

**Repository - getPostCountsByMonth**

```
public function getPostCountsByMonth($year, $month)
{
    // Query for blog posts in each month
    $date = new \DateTime("{$year}-{$month}-01");
    $toDate = clone $date;
    $toDate->modify("next month midnight -1 second");

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('post')
        ->where('post.created BETWEEN :start AND :end')
        ->addOrderBy('post.created', 'DESC')
        ->setParameter('start', $date)
        ->setParameter('end', $toDate);

    $query->select('COUNT(post.created)');

    $month = $query
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    return $month;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo inside your getPostCount method `$this->$em` you should remove the $ sign because you want to access `em` property so use `$this->em->...`

Comment: Perfect!!! Can't believe I missed seeing that. Thank you so MUCH! Please make this an answer and I will happily accept it, sir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo inside your `getPostCount()` method.

On this line `$this->$em` you should remove the second $ sign because you want to access `em` property so you should use it like this:

```
$post = $this->em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Post')
    ->getPostCountsByMonth($year, $month);
```